# Increment value from void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to modify some variables [not necessary from the same class/struct] from keyboard's shortcuts, something like that:
A foo struct containing variables:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    float b;
};

struct Foo2 {
    int c;
};
```

And a main like:

```
int main() {
    Foo f;
    Foo2 f2
    void* p = &(f.a); //it could be &(f2.c)

    if ('A' key activated) {
        *p += 1;
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm stucked at this point:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')
```

The only way to make it work is to change:

```
*p += 1;
```

By:

```
*(int*)p += 1;
```

Which is not a good solution, because I should not know the type pointed by p. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well, how would the compiler know what `+=` means if it doesn't know the type? Why are you casting the struct to `void*` at all?

Comment: In fact, I'd like to store all these "bindings" in a map, 'A' key modifying foo.a, 'B' for foo.b, 'C' for foo.c ... so the type could be fload or int. What should be the right cast then?

Comment: what you want is late member variable binding.  there are ways to do this in c++, but you need to build a little bit of an infrastructure.  one of which (that everyone hates) is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245115.  I am sure there are others... just google for it.  I think xpcom is the free version that is commonly used in linux and opensource community.

Comment: yes, thanks for the name! I'll look at that, but it seems a bit overkill for my needs here; I will follow lethal-guitar solution for this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* At first I didn't realize that you want to have different types per entry. Based on the task of handling keyboard shortcuts, you could use a polymorphic class, and put instances of it into a std::map:

```
class KeyHandler {
public:
    virtual void onKeyStroke() = 0;
};

class MyHandler : public KeyHandler {
public:
    MyHandler(int& value) : myValue(value) {}

    virtual void onKeyStroke() {
        myValue_ += 1;
    }

private:
    int& myValue_; // Other subclasses could have other data
};

// Now place instances of different Handlers into a std::map
typedef std::shared_ptr<KeyHandler> PKeyHandler;
std::map<char, PKeyHandler> bindings;

bindings['A'] = PKeyHandler(new IncrementIntHandler(&someInt)); 
bindings['B'] = PKeyHandler(new IncrementFloatHandler(&someFloat));


// The actual input handler then just invokes
// the correct handler for a key stroke.
bindings[keyCode]->onKeyStroke();
```

That way, you can define a handler class for every action you want to support, and implement the corresponding logic into these classes. You could make the base class' implementation just do nothing to handle non-mapped keys, etc.

Comment: that won't work because he wants the type to vary.  they're not all int, so now you have to create a type object, and have float,int, etc. wrappers inherited from it.

Comment: Edited now with a possible approach for what he might be trying to achieve

Comment: Hmm yes, it might works great :) Currently I made an awful #define BIND macro, which creates void(void) functions, and I bind one key to one function... your solution is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the pointer to void* lost the type information and the compiler will not know how to increment. Why don't you make a pointer to Foo instead?

```
int main() {
    Foo f;
    Foo* p = &f;

    if ('A' key activated) {
        p->a += 1;
    }
}
```

**Also keep in mind that incrementing a float is not a good idea!**

For the quesion in the comment of this answer:

```
struct FooBar
{
    int *a;
    float *b;
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    Bar b;
    FooBar fb{&f.a, &b.b};

    if ('A' key activated) {
        *(fb.a) += 1;
    }
}
```

Note that this solution is rather C-style. Look at lethal-guitar's answer for a more C++-style solution.

Comment: And for that matter, why not just use the original name.  f.a++;

Comment: I would do that but in my case these variables are in separated structures. So that trick won't work, will it?

Comment: You should have put that in the question. Well, you could make a structure that contains pointers to the correct locations.

Comment: my bad, I wanted to clarify as much as possible the question but it was finally inaccurate.. by the way, I'll use c++-style lethal-guitar but glad to know there is a solution in C too

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use an `int` pointer instead:

```
int * p = &f.a;

if ( /* condition */ ) { ++*p; }
```

Comment: "Which is not a good solution, because I should not know the type pointed by p"